# How do you edit the value of one column based on the value of two other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image: Dataframe]

I am using a dataframe called `df_PCC7942`. In the above screenshot I would like to able to edit the 'AVG Log2 Ratio' to say the word 'Blank' if either the Pvalue or Qvalue is above 0.05

I tried

```py
if df_PCC7942.loc[(df_PCC7942['Pvalue']> 0.05) | (df_PCC7942['Qvalue']>0.05) ]:
    df_PCC7942.loc[df_PCC7942['AVG Log2 Ratio']] = 'Blank'
```

However was met with the error

ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

If someone could help me out that would be really appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a single comparison on all the relevant columns and [`any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) to aggregate to a single boolean per row:

```
m = df_PCC7942[['Pvalue', 'Qvalue']].gt(0.05).any(axis=1)
df_PCC7942.loc[m, "AVG Log2 Ratio"] = "Blank"
```

As a one liner:

```
df_PCC7942.loc[df_PCC7942[['Pvalue', 'Qvalue']].gt(0.05).any(axis=1), "AVG Log2 Ratio"] = "Blank"
```

Or use 2 conditions:

```
m1 = df_PCC7942['Pvalue'].gt(0.05)
m2 = df_PCC7942['Qvalue'].gt(0.05)
df_PCC7942.loc[m1&m2, "AVG Log2 Ratio"] = "Blank"
```